# hovering over a button and changing its properties html/js/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to implement a button which draws a border around itself when a user's mouse is over it. I've written the following code in `index.html`:

```
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <button onclick="location.href='http://www.github.com/xxxxx'" 
                    onmouseover="outline(this)" onmouseout="unoutline(this)"
                    type="button">GitHub</button>
                </h1>

                <script>
                    function outline(x){
                        x.style.border = none;
                    }
                    
                    function unoutline(x){
                        x.style.border = solid;
                    }
                </script>
```

The actual linking part of the button works as expected- upon clicking, the button redirects the user to the GitHub link. However, when the mouse hovers over the button, there is no change. This could be because (1) `outline` is not being called correctly when the mouse hovers over the button, or more likely (2) because I'm changing the properties incorrectly in the `outline` function. I'm assuming it's (2), since it doesn't seem like I'm able to access the css attributes of a button via `Element.style`.

Could anyone shed some insight on why the border is not appearing when a user hovers over the button?

Comment: Instead of using `js` use `css` for this `button:hover { outline: 2px red; }` it will be more simple and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS styles on JS are strings. The right way to set values on them is with between quotes. Example:

```
    x.style.border = 'none';
    x.style.border = 'solid';
```

instead of:

```
    x.style.border = none;
    x.style.border = solid;
```

In the second case, JS is interpreting none and solid as variables.

Answer (score 1):

check this... now it is working.

```html
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.github.com/xxxxx'" 
                    onmouseover="outline(this)" onmouseout="unoutline(this)"
                    type="button">GitHub</button>
                </h1>

                <script>
                    function outline(x){
                        x.style.border = 'none';
                    }
                    
                    function unoutline(x){
                        x.style.border = 'solid';
                    }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The property `solid` or `none` won't work in javascript becuase css properties are strings in javascript.

So try

> `x.style.border = "none";`

and

> `x.style.border="solid"`

Comment: I understand that you don't have enough reputation to comment but this is not a way to answer questions.